# VS6 COM App Crashing with Potential Memory Integrity Error

Tags: dll, com, mfc

We're porting an old Visual Studio 6 application to Windows 7. The application heavily uses COM and the old RogueWave database interface. We're having a very random sever crash which looks like some sort of memory integrity problem. The crash occurs in the COM application. The application is started using COM, after starting up it tries to connect to the database. One of the following will occur:

1) Sometimes the COM application will have a sever crash

2) Sometimes it will work

3) Sometimes it will not be able to connect to the database and never will even with retries.

4) Sometimes when calling the RogueWave database creation, it does not return.
When starting the COM application several times in a row it will display any number of these symptoms.

At this point I have not been able to identify what is causing the instability.

The application will also crash when started normally, not using COM, but crashes less frequently.

Previously I saw a problem with identical symptoms in another area of this product. I was able to identify that the symptoms were tied to calls into a dll which were returning a CString that was created as a local variable. The dll is built using _AFXDLL preprocessor definition. After removing the calls to this dll this problem no longer occurs. This problem was occurring in many places.

At first I thought that this problem was caused because the dll was not built as an AFX EXTENSION DLL, but after reading through the documentation the _AFXDLL preprocessor definition will also build the dll as an AFX_EXTENSION_DLL. I'm used to using the _AFXEXT preprocessor directive to build AFX_EXTENSION dlls.

The COM application that is now crashing does not use this DLL. There is another DLL used by the COM application that has 1 exported function that returns a CString created as a local variable. This exported function is not called during the database connection.

Anyone have any ideas what would be causing this apparent memory integrity crash in a COM application? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is the universal bat signal for latent heap corruption.  There is tooling available to help you diagnose it, you need to go shopping.  Tough shopping list when your compiler and libraries are this ancient and the problem has been ignored for this long.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be caused by a bug in the Oracle 10g express client dll.